# Get all parents from javascript recursive function based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I've two objects:

**1. menudata:**

> "[{"category_id":6,"category_name":"Menu1","parent_id":1,"type":"folder","parent_name":"Menu1","page_path":"-","state":"1528796405091"},{"category_id":7,"category_name":"A","parent_id":6,"type":"folder","parent_name":"A","page_path":"-","state":"1528796433246"},{"category_id":8,"category_name":"B","parent_id":7,"type":"folder","parent_name":"B","page_path":"-","state":"1528796433298"},{"category_id":9,"category_name":"C","parent_id":8,"type":"folder","parent_name":"C","page_path":"-","state":"1528796433340"},{"category_id":10,"category_name":"D","parent_id":9,"type":"folder","parent_name":"D","page_path":"-","state":"1528796433394"},{"category_id":451,"category_name":"E","parent_id":10,"type":"file","parent_name":"E","page_path":"abc","state":"1528796433423"},{"category_id":103,"category_name":"UserPreferences","parent_id":3,"type":"file","parent_name":"UserPreferences","page_path":"../../jsp/configuration/UserPreferences.jsp","state":null},{"category_id":101,"category_name":"AddUser","parent_id":4,"type":"file","parent_name":"AddUser","page_path":"../../jsp/configuration/newuser.jsp","state":null},{"category_id":4,"category_name":"UserAccess","parent_id":2,"type":"folder","parent_name":"UserAccess","page_path":"-","state":null},{"category_id":3,"category_name":"Preferences","parent_id":2,"type":"folder","parent_name":"Preferences","page_path":"-","state":null},{"category_id":2,"category_name":"SystemAdministration","parent_id":1,"type":"folder","parent_name":"SystemAdministration","page_path":"-","state":null}]"

**2. menurolesdata:**

> "[{"page_id":101,"category_id":4},{"page_id":103,"category_id":3},{"page_id":451,"category_id":10}]"

Here menudata object contains all the parent-child (pageid and categoryid) records while menurolesdata contains those parent and child which have some specific access. So basically I want only those records which are present in menurolesdata along with all there parents until it gets no parent.

Ex. page_id 451 in menurolesdata has parent 10, 10 has parent 9, 9 has parent 8, 8 has parent 7, 7 has parent 6, 6 has parent 1 and 1 has no parent.

So basically I want to filter menudata based on menurolesdata.

Note: page_id in menurolesdata are same as category_id in menudata

Following is my code:

```
getMenu() {
    Promise.all([this.dashboardServerice.getMenuBar(), this.dashboardServerice.getMenuRolesDetails()).then((result) => {

          let menuData = result[0];
          let menuRolesData = result[1];            

          menuData.forEach((item,index) => {                        
            menuRolesData.forEach((data,key) => {                               
                if(data.page_id == item.category_id && data.category_id == item.parent_id){                     
                    console.log("item===<>", item);                     
                    this.getAllParent(menuData, data.page_id);                      
                }                               
            });        
          });             
        });
  }


// Following is my getAllParent() recursive function:

getAllParent(arr, pageid) {
        let result = [];
        for(let i in arr) {
            if(arr[i].category_id == pageid) {
                let parent = this.getAllParent(arr, arr[i].parent_id)

                if(parent.length) {
                    arr[i].parent_id = parent
                }
                result.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
        console.log("result ====================", result);
        return result
    }
```

Here I'm getting only single result i.e. 
`{category_id: 101, category_name: "AddUser", parent_id: Array(1), type: "file", parent_name: "AddUser", …}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that I think works like you wanted, though it can be optimized

```
const menuData = [{ "category_id": 6, "category_name": "Menu1", "parent_id": 1, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "Menu1", "page_path": "-", "state": "1528796405091" }, { "category_id": 7, "category_name": "A", "parent_id": 6, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "A", "page_path": "-", "state": "1528796433246" }, { "category_id": 8, "category_name": "B", "parent_id": 7, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "B", "page_path": "-", "state": "1528796433298" }, { "category_id": 9, "category_name": "C", "parent_id": 8, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "C", "page_path": "-", "state": "1528796433340" }, { "category_id": 10, "category_name": "D", "parent_id": 9, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "D", "page_path": "-", "state": "1528796433394" }, { "category_id": 451, "category_name": "E", "parent_id": 10, "type": "file", "parent_name": "E", "page_path": "abc", "state": "1528796433423" }, { "category_id": 103, "category_name": "UserPreferences", "parent_id": 3, "type": "file", "parent_name": "UserPreferences", "page_path": "../../jsp/configuration/UserPreferences.jsp", "state": null }, { "category_id": 101, "category_name": "AddUser", "parent_id": 4, "type": "file", "parent_name": "AddUser", "page_path": "../../jsp/configuration/newuser.jsp", "state": null }, { "category_id": 4, "category_name": "UserAccess", "parent_id": 2, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "UserAccess", "page_path": "-", "state": null }, { "category_id": 3, "category_name": "Preferences", "parent_id": 2, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "Preferences", "page_path": "-", "state": null }, { "category_id": 2, "category_name": "SystemAdministration", "parent_id": 1, "type": "folder", "parent_name": "SystemAdministration", "page_path": "-", "state": null }];

const menuRolesData = [{ "page_id": 101, "category_id": 4 }, { "page_id": 103, "category_id": 3 }, { "page_id": 451, "category_id": 10 }];

function getMenuData(all, role) {
    let menu = menuData.find(menu => menu.category_id === role.page_id);

    while (menu) {
        all.add(menu);
        menu = menuData.find(parent => parent.category_id === menu.parent_id);
    }

    return all;
}

const result = menuRolesData.reduce((all, role) => getMenuData(all, role), new Set());

console.log(Array.from(result));
```

And here is editor [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4nuqnh)

Comment: It would be great if you explain how reduce function working and how parameters are getting handled for them

Comment: `reduce` takes a callback, and initial value for the accumulator. The callback takes two arguments: accumulator and array element. In the first cycle the first argument of callback will be set to the initial value that you have passed to reduce function. In the next cycles return value of the previous callback call becomes the first argument of the current callback call. It continues till the end of the array, and at the end reduce function returns the last value of the accumulator, which is return value of the last callback call.

Comment: Thanks for help. Here I'm getting one issue actually. I'm getting parent of `451` upto "A" only but its root parent is `Menu1` actually. So recursion is not working till end